# Reset "Running Total Field" on new page

Tags: crystal-reports, cumulative-sum

My report table has 10 columns. A Running Total `Sno` counts the number of rows on each page. `Sno` needs to reset when the page changes, rather than continuing the count

I tried using `PageNumber <> previous(PageNumber)` to reset the Runnint Total. But this gives an error because (PageNumber) has no previous value.

How can I reset `Sno` when the page changes?

[image: Report and Formula]

Comment: Previous will only work for Database fields but not for special fields so previous doesn't work, Hence you need to manually manipulate the page count and reset the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a job for shared variables.

Set up a formula in the Page Header to reset your Count variable to zero. Then create another formula that increments Count for each record.

In theory, Count will function as a Total Per Page.